# vxworks system call trap mechanism

Tags: c, operating-system, low-level, vxworks

I'm new to VxWorks and working with an ELF binary for VxWorks. System calls appear to trap into the kernel by calling the address `_func_syscallTrapHandle` which is `0x1234`. Since the program must transition into the kernel, am I correct in assuming that the goal of this is to segfault by accessing low memory to enter the kernel? If so does the segfault ISR check the contents of `rax` and, when it's `0x1234` perform systemcall logic? Why isn't the `syscall` instruction used instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are describing the system call trap mechanism in vxsim; as VxWorks, in this case, is executed as normal process inside Linux or Windows it cannot use syscall instruction.
An elf binary for real hardware behaves differently.

Comment: thanks so much, this is really helpful